# NSFetchResultsController with sectionsNameKeyPath and order of results

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having a bit of trouble with NSFetchResultsController and looking for a little help.

My CoreData entity `FunCentre` has the following attributes `name`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `country`, `postcode` and `favourite`. When a user selects a row in the tableview it sets the `favourite` attribute to 1 and when tapped again it sets it back to 0. This all works fine as i've checked the sqlite file and the changes are happening correctly.

I want to use sections to separate the rows favourited and those that are not. I want the favourites to be listed at the top of the tableview in the first section and the rest of the list to be in second section.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
sectionNameKeyPath:@"favourite"
         cacheName:nil];
```

The above code works whilst in the app and changing the favourites, however when I close the app and relaunch it the favourites aren't grouped and just appear alphabetically in the main list, it does still put the correct number of rows in the favourite section.

SQL Debug Results

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST FROM Z_METADATA

CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCOUNTRY, t0.ZFAVOURITE, t0.ZLATITUDE,  t0.ZLONGITUDE, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZPOSTCODE FROM ZFUNCENTRE t0 ORDER BY t0.ZNAME

CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0051s

CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0106s for 34 rows.

CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.ZFAVOURITE, COUNT (DISTINCT  t0.Z_PK) FROM ZFUNCENTRE t0 GROUP BY  t0.ZFAVOURITE ORDER BY t0.ZFAVOURITE
```

Can anyone tell me why the grouping isn't working on relaunch? and also how do I change the order of the grouping? as the favourites appear at the bottom and I want them at the top.

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sectionNameKeyPath`, you must add a sort descriptor using the same key (or at least generating the same relative orderings):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"favourite" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort1, sort2, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, That solved the problem on launch with the order. How do I change the section order? I want favourites at the top and the rest of list underneath, its currently in reverse.

Comment: @MattPrice: Change `ascending:YES` to `ascending:NO` :-)